# Java, Google Drive : Why does GoogleAPI sometime does not give refresh token when authorized?

Tags: java, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a Spring-MVC project in which I have integrated Google Drive functionality to upload attachments to google drive. To do that, I used their sample code, and modified it. Now, whenever I authorize, I am getting a Credential object and I am saving the access-token and refresh-token in the DB.

The problem is sometimes Google decides to give me refresh-token and sometimes out of the blue, it doesn't. This is causing a problem as without the refresh-token while making a request, I am getting a 401.

***So, what is this whimsical nature when sometimes I don't get the refresh-token?*** 
Here is my code for authorize, storeCredentials, gettingStoredCredentials and saving a file.

```
     @Override
        public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
            InputStream in =
                    DriveQuickstartImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                    GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                            .setAccessType("offline")
                            .build();
            Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                    flow, new com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
            if (credential != null) {
                storeCredentials(credential);
                return credential;
            }
            return null;
        }

 @Override
    public void storeCredentials(Credential credential) {
        Person person = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        if (!(credential == null)) {
            person.setGoogleDrive(true);
            this.personService.updatePerson(person);
            GoogleDrive googleDrive = new GoogleDrive();
            googleDrive.setAccessToken(credential.getAccessToken());
            googleDrive.setRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken());
            this.googleDriveService.saveCredentials(googleDrive, person.getId());
        }
    }

  private Credential getStoredCredentials(Long groupAccountid) {
        try {
            GroupAccount groupAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupAccountid);
            Person person = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(groupAccount.getAdminUsername());
            if (person.isGoogleDrive()) {
                GoogleDrive googleDrive = this.googleDriveService.getUsersGoogleDrive(person.getId());
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setClientSecrets(clientid, clientsecret).build();
                credential.setAccessToken(googleDrive.getAccessToken());
                credential.setRefreshToken(googleDrive.getRefreshToken());
                return credential;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }


 @Override
    public File insertFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, int noteid, Long groupAccountId, String folderId) {
        try {
            GroupAccount groupAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupAccountId);
            Person person = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(groupAccount.getAdminUsername());
            if (person.isGoogleDrive()) {
                Credential credential = getStoredCredentials(groupAccountId);
                Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null).
                        setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).
                        setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                body.setMimeType(multipartFile.getContentType());
                body.setOriginalFilename(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

                body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(folderId)));
                InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(multipartFile.getContentType(),
                        new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream()));
                try {
                    File file = driveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                    this.groupAttachmentsService.addGoogleDriveAttachment(file.getWebContentLink(), multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(),
                            file.getFileSize(), noteid, file.getId(), multipartFile);
                    insertPermission(driveService, file.getId(), "default", "anyone", "reader");
                    return file;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Error log :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

I am checking the values in DB and I can see that whenever the refresh-token is empty, I get a 401, or else I can upload files. But the code used is always the same. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the refresh token will be given only when the user is prompted with a consent screen. you can use setApprovalPrompt to 'force' to always get the refresh token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-case if someone has a problem, then setApprovalPrompt to 'force' and setAccessType to 'offline' is what was necessary. One can change the authorization code to what I am giving below :

```
@Override
    public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        InputStream in =
                DriveQuickstartImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        if (credential != null) {
            storeCredentials(credential);
            return credential;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If any help is needed, just drop a comment.

Comment: the actual issue is that google gives the refresh token once only (not out of the blue, its not random). if you didnt save it it wont give it again unless you force it. forcing every time i think reduces security by exposing the refresh token more times it needs to.